# Parse request with JSON.parse

Tags: json, node.js, express

I try to parse a request with `node.js`, So I build the next:

```
 app.get('/download', function(req, res){
      var parseJson = JSON.parse(req);
      var file = parseJson.fileName;
      res.download(file); // Set disposition and send it.
    });
```

And I send a request with the Advanced Rest Client:

URL: `http://localhost:5000/download`

Method: `GET`

Raw arguments: `fileInfo: "C://1//239698_n.jpg"`

and it gives me the next error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token o
    at Object.parse (native)
    at port (c:\Node\nodejs\express.js:13:24)
    at callbacks (c:\Node\nodejs\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:164:37)
    at param (c:\Node\nodejs\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:138:11)
    at pass (c:\Node\nodejs\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:145:5)
    at Router._dispatch (c:\Node\nodejs\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:173:5)
    at Object.router (c:\Node\nodejs\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:33:10)
```

What can be the reson?

Comment: have you tried logging `request` and confirming it is valid JSON?

Comment: If you're using express, you can probably just skip the `JSON.parse` step.  I don't think the data you want is in `req`, but rather `req.query`

Comment: That's probably a better answer than mine below, if Express provides a direct way to get at your data then that should be the preferred way to do it

Answer (score 1):

You're not sending JSON.  You're sending querystring formatted arguments.  You'll want to use [querystring.parse()](http://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html) or [node-querystring](https://github.com/visionmedia/node-querystring) or, shameless plug alert, my module that is format agnostic, [objectifier](https://github.com/jmshinn/objectifier).